# Identify “duplicates” within a table by using GROUP BY column1 OR column2

Tags: mysql, group-by

Generally speaking, I want to group by one column OR by another one:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM foo
GROUP BY column1 OR column2
```

In particular, I want to identify duplicates within a given table, below an example with minimal data.

## Minimal example

```
| id | name       | birth_date   | email                        |
|---:|:-----------|:-------------|:-----------------------------|
|  1 | 'Gamow'    | '1904-03-04' | 'george.gamow@science.ua'    |
|  2 | 'Gamow'    | NULL         | NULL                         |
|  3 | 'Gamow'    | '1904-03-04' | NULL                         |
|  4 | 'Gamow'    | '1904-03-04' | 'george-gamow@science.ua'    |
|  5 | 'Gamow'    | NULL         | 'george.gamow@science.ua'    |
|  6 | 'Feynman'  | '1918-05-11' | 'richard.feynman@science.us' |
|  7 | 'Feynman'  | '1918-05-11' | NULL                         |
|  8 | 'Poincaré' | '1854-04-29' | 'henri.poincare@science.fr'  |
```

Two people are considered duplicates if they have the same name AND (the same birth date OR the same email).
I would like to find a query who gives

- `MIN(id)` among the duplicates: the line to keep
- the 1+ other ids: the line(s) to delete

I wrote this query

```sql
SELECT 
    MIN(p.id) AS id_tokeep,
    REPLACE(
        GROUP_CONCAT(p.id ORDER BY p.id ASC SEPARATOR ','),
        CONCAT(MIN(p.id), ','),
        ''
    ) AS ids_todelete,
    MIN(p.name) AS name
FROM people AS p
WHERE p.birth_date IS NOT NULL OR p.email IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY p.name, (p.birth_date IS NOT NULL) OR (p.email IS NOT NULL)
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
ORDER BY id_tokeep;
```

which works:

```
| id_tokeep | ids_todelete | name      |
|----------:|--------------|-----------|
|         1 | '3,4,5'      | 'Gamow'   |
|         6 | '7'          | 'Feynman' |
```

except:

- it feels like a hack (as I didn’t find anywhere the use of `OR` inside a `GROUP BY` clause),
- it sometimes generate a warning « `Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'george.gamow@science.ua'` »
- with real data, it returns « strange » results (which seems to confirm that it is a hack).

Hence, my questions are:

- is it « legal » to use OR within a GROUP BY clause?
- if not, how to re-write this query without the OR within the GROUP BY?

## SQL code to generate the minimal example

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people;

CREATE TABLE people (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    birth_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO people (name, birth_date, email)
VALUES
    ('Gamow', '1904-03-04', 'george.gamow@science.ua'),  -- 1
    ('Gamow', NULL, NULL),  -- 2
    ('Gamow', '1904-03-04', NULL),  -- 3
    ('Gamow', '1904-03-04', 'george-gamow@science.ua'),  -- 4
    ('Gamow', NULL, 'george.gamow@science.ua'),  -- 5
    ('Feynman', '1918-05-11', 'richard.feynman@science.us'),  -- 6
    ('Feynman', '1918-05-11', NULL),  -- 7
    ('Poincaré', '1854-04-29', 'henri.poincare@science.fr')  -- 8
;
```

## Other trial query

I tried with two self-join, but I then struggle to group the duplicates:

```sql
SELECT 
    p1.id AS patient_id,
    p2.id AS patient_match_birth_date_id,
    p3.id AS patient_match_email_id
FROM people AS p1
    JOIN people AS p2 ON p2.birth_date = p1.birth_date
    JOIN people AS p3 ON p3.email = p1.email
ORDER BY p1.id, p2.id, p3.id;
```

I tried with a union between the duplicate on birth date and the duplicate on email, but it returns retundant data:

```
WITH patient_matches AS (
    (
        SELECT 
            p1.id AS patient_id,
            p2.id AS patient_match_id
        FROM people AS p1
            JOIN people AS p2 ON p2.birth_date = p1.birth_date
        ORDER BY p1.id ASC 
    )
    UNION ALL 
    (
        SELECT 
            p1.id AS patient_id,
            p2.id AS patient_match_id
        FROM people AS p1
            JOIN people AS p2 ON p2.email = p1.email
        ORDER BY p1.id ASC 
    )
    ORDER BY patient_match_id
)
SELECT json_arrayagg(pm.patient_id)
FROM patient_matches AS pm
GROUP BY pm.patient_match_id;
```

Comment: `OR` produces true/false value, where `true` is represented as `1` and `false` as '0`.  What do you _want_ `OR` to mean inside `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Yep, exactly, this is what I say in my (own) accepted answer.
Initialy, I wrongly assume that the `OR` would be understand within the `GROUP BY` context (i.e. semantically different from the basic logical `OR`), but it’s not. Hence it is not possible to do what I want with a simple `GROUP BY` and I find another way with mainly a self-`JOIN` with specific `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution, there is two points:

1. The `OR` within a `GROUP BY` clause is not interpreted in a `GROUP BY`-context, it is just a simple `OR`, ie `(p.birth_date IS NOT NULL) OR (p.email IS NOT NULL)` within `GROUP BY p.name, ...` is the same as within `SELECT ...`; it gave the impression of working because in the sample data above, columns `birth_date` and `email` was either `NULL` either equals.
2. Afaik, it is not possible to use a `GROUP BY` to identify the duplicates, one has to use a self-join as below.

## Using self-`JOIN` with specific `ON` clause

This query:

```sql
WITH duplicates AS (
    SELECT 
        p1.id AS p1_id,
        p2.id AS p2_id
    FROM people AS p1
        JOIN people AS p2
            ON p2.name = p1.name 
            AND
            (
                (
                    p2.birth_date IS NOT NULL 
                    AND p1.birth_date IS NOT NULL 
                    AND p2.birth_date = p1.birth_date
                )
                OR
                (
                    p2.email IS NOT NULL
                    AND p1.email IS NOT NULL 
                    AND p2.email = p1.email
                )
            )
            AND p2.id > p1.id 
)
SELECT
    d.p1_id AS id_tokeep,
    GROUP_CONCAT(d.p2_id ORDER BY d.p2_id SEPARATOR ',') AS ids_tomerge
FROM duplicates AS d
WHERE d.p1_id NOT IN (SELECT p2_id FROM duplicates)
GROUP BY d.p1_id
ORDER BY d.p1_id
```

whose key elements are:

- self-`JOIN` with the criteria of what 2 duplicates are, ie: same name AND (same birth date OR same email),
- the `p2.id > p1.id` ensure that a line does not match with itself and eliminate the symmetric duplicates (eg: line 2 is a duplicate of line 1, so is line 1 of line 2; then this condition eliminate the “line 1 is a duplicate of line 2”),
- the `d.p1_id NOT IN (SELECT p2_id FROM duplicates)` ensure the uniqueness of the line to keep;

gives exactly the result I looked for: the id of the line to keep and the ids of the lines to merge.

E.g. with these data:

```
| "id" | "name"     | "birth_date" | "email"                      |
|-----:|------------|--------------|------------------------------|
|    1 | "Gamow"    | "1904-03-04" | "george.gamow@science.ua"    |
|    2 | "Gamow"    | "1904-03-04" | NULL                         |
|    3 | "Gamow"    | "1904-03-04" | "george-gamow@science.ua"    |
|    4 | "Gamow"    | NULL         | "george.gamow@science.ua"    |
|    5 | "Gamow"    | NULL         | NULL                         |
|    6 | "Gamow"    | "1904-03-05" | NULL                         |
|    7 | "Gamow"    | NULL         | "gamow@science.ua"           |
|    8 | "Feynman"  | "1918-05-11" | "richard.feynman@science.us" |
|    9 | "Feynman"  | "1918-05-11" | NULL                         |
|   10 | "Feynman"  | "1918-05-11" | NULL                         |
|   11 | "Poincaré" | "1854-04-29" | "henri.poincare@science.fr"  |
|   12 | "Poincaré" | "1854-04-29" | "henri.poincare@science.fr"  |
|   13 | "Poincaré" | "1986-04-04" | "henri.poincare@email.fr"    |
|   14 | "Poincaré" | "1986-04-04" | "henri.poincare@email.fr"    |
|   15 | "Poincaré" | NULL         | "henri.poincare@email.fr"    |
```

the result are:

```
| "id_tokeep" | "ids_tomerge" |
|------------:|---------------|
|           1 | "2,3,4"       |
|           8 | "9,10"        |
|          11 | "12"          |
|          13 | "14,15"       |
```

Try this on [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT).

NB: Using `JSON_ARRAYAGG` instead of `GROUP_CONCAT` would have been better (because the `int` type of the ids would have been conserved), but there is no (simple) way to sort the elements within a `JSON_ARRAYAGG` (cf [this issue](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94696); as I wanted the ids to merge to be sorted, I have to use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 0):

## What I propose ?

Unique rows in your case  can be found by using

```
select min(p.id) id,
       p.name
from people p
inner join (select min(id) id,
                   name
            from people
            group by name,email 
          )  x on x.id=p.id
group by p.name,p.birth_date
```

Create another table people_new

```
create table people_new  (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    birth_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

Use insert into select to insert `unique` rows

```
insert into people_new ( select * 
                         from people 
                         where id in ( select min(p.id) id
                                       from people p
                                       inner join (select min(id) id
                                                from people
                                                group by name,email 
                                                )  x on x.id=p.id
                                    group by p.name,p.birth_date
                                    )
                        )
```

Select on people_new would give the following result.

```
id  name      birth_date    email
 1  Gamow     1904-03-04    george.gamow@science.ua
 2  Gamow     null          null
 6  Feynman   1918-05-11    richard.feynman@science.us
 8  Poincaré  1854-04-29    henri.poincare@science.fr
```

[Check fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wmfmMhbX)

At the end you can rename the tables and drop the old table if you don't need it anymore.

```
SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES people WRITE;
ALTER TABLE `people` RENAME people_old;
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;


SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES people_new WRITE;
ALTER TABLE `people_new` RENAME people;
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Note, delete is a heavy process , better us insert into select and drop the old table.

Comment: Thanks :-)! It would work, but I cannot use this solution because (i) I have to log the merged duplicates, and (ii) the real table is in production within an application, so there is no way I can replace it!